# Volume button bug ios7

Tags: iphone, audio, ios

I've run into a weird bug that either turns my volume up to max or turns it down to mute. Whenever I have my phone in my pocket and I want to change the volume, I kind of press the buttons on the side with a bit of luck. 
However, it sometimes happens that I press both buttons very shortly (milliseconds) after each other, triggering this bug.

In some way, the phone turns the volume up or down continuously, no matter if you press a volume button, it will always go to max or mute again.

Now, I've figured out that restarting the phone fixes this, but I was wondering if someone else has noticed this and if there is a fix that doesn't need restarting. As far as I know, this only happens under iOS7, never noticed it before that.

Edit: Almost a year later and one iOS-version later, I am STILL noticing this bug once in a while. Still haven't found a way to replicate it.

Comment: Is this when playing music, or changing the volume during a phone-call or when? Jailbroken?

Comment: This is when listening to music and changing the volume while my phone is in my pocket. It's not Jailbroken.

Comment: I get this same thing, and have done for a few years, very occasionally. It's occurring even on my new iPhone 6 (happened twice now)

Answer (score 1):

Having just spent the last 2 minutes or so spamming my volume buttons in various ways and not been able to reproduce this, I'm pretty confident that it's not an iOS 7 bug, or at least not an iPad iOS 7 bug.

It might be extreme, but you could try backing up and restoring the device, which should fix iOS problems such as this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying. I just tried to replicate what happens in my pocket (screen off, music playing) and could replicate it once. Tried it without the cover (after restarting my phone), couldn't replicate it. Tried it again with my cover on, couldn't replicate it. The only explanation I have is that there was something stuck on the volume buttons in my cover, because I can't replicate it anymore.